# Parsing and using proxys with aiohttp inside the get argument

Tags: python, asynchronous, proxy, python-requests, aiohttp

I am using aiohttps to send a get request. Previously I was using the standard requests module but after switching to aiohttps I started getting proxy errors.

Heres my proxy config:

```py
 with open('proxies.txt', 'r') as f:
      lines = f.read().split("\n")
      split_proxies = [line.split(":") for line in lines]
      proxies = [{'http:':f"http://{p[2]}:{p[3]}@{p[0]}:{p[1]}",'https:':f"https://{p[2]}:{p[3]}@{p[0]}:{p[1]}"} for p in split_proxies]
      print(split_proxies)
```

And heres my code:

```py
async def Requests_loop():
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
    async with s.get(url, headers=headers, proxy=random.choice(proxies)) as r:
```

When using a proxies argument it would throw me an unexpected argument error and once I read the documentation it said to use proxy instead. However, I get this error:

```
   async with s.get(url, headers=headers, proxy=random.choice(proxies)) as r:
  File "C:\Users\royce\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\royce\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 391, in _request
    proxy = URL(proxy)
  File "C:\Users\royce\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\yarl\_url.py", line 152, in __new__
    raise TypeError("Constructor parameter should be str")
TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str
```

Comment: Try printing `url`.

Comment: the url is good it was working fine when i was just using normal requests and the same proxies

Comment: Print `random.choice(proxies)`. It needs to be a string.

Comment: after turning it into a string it said only http proxies are accepted but after changing it still says only http proxies supported. Heres an example of what is printed if i do print proxies
http://rp_user_1321:Nqn8VLlsdXDeyojd_country-UnitedKingdom_session-RPadasda@prov.rampageproxies.com:311123